# Updating different tables data which has similar same header

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I updating few tables in different sheets from one source table data, which has similar headings where the destination tables have some additional headers.

[image]

And i was using the below VBA code, however its very difficult if i'm swapping the headers.

```js
 
    
   
    lastRow = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Report").Range("B8:B" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("D8:D" & lastRow).Value
    
    
    lastRow = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Report").Range("C8:C" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("F8:F" & lastRow).Value
    
    
    lastRow = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Report").Range("E8:E" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("H8:H" & lastRow).Value
    
    
    lastRow = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Report").Range("F8:F" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("E8:E" & lastRow).Value
```

Is there a better way to update the data based on the table header?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "swapping the headers"? do you mean you might insert columns into the destination with no counterpart in source? should Header1 in source always go to Header1 in destination?

Comment: Yes the headers will be same, however it will not be in order as same as the source. Example Header1 may be placed in any one of column in the destination table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my own flexible code. Please tell me if you have any other way thanks again :)

```css
Sub updatetbl()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim col As Range, col1 As Range
Dim source As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet
Dim i As String, j As Integer
Set source = Sheets("Data")
Set dest = Sheets("Report")
' setting table headers as range
Set col = source.Range("Data[#Headers]")
Set col1 = dest.Range("Report[#Headers]")

For Each cell In col

    For Each cell1 In col1
    i = cell.Value
    If cell.Value = cell1.Value Then
    source.Select
    ' selecting matched table header column 
    Range("Data[" & i & "]").Copy
    dest.Select
    cell1.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ' pasting the respective data under destination header
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Next cell1
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are looking for, it iterates through the source columns, finds that column on the destination sheet and then pastes the column over (this could be simplified by pasting the entire column instead of looking for the last row and just copying the range, but you can figure that out if you want :) Change the constants declarations to fit your situation.

```
Const SourceSheetName = "Sheet28"
Const DestinationSheetName = "Sheet29"
Const HeaderRow = 1

Dim wss As Worksheet
Dim wsd As Worksheet

Sub CopyByHeader()
    Set wss = Sheets(SourceSheetName)
    Set wsd = Sheets(DestinationSheetName)
    SourceColCount = wss.Cells(HeaderRow, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    DestColCount = wsd.Cells(HeaderRow, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    wsd.Rows("2:1000000").Clear
    For SourceCol = 1 To SourceColCount
        HeaderText = wss.Cells(HeaderRow, SourceCol)
        DestCol = 1
        Do Until wsd.Cells(HeaderRow, DestCol) = HeaderText
            DestCol = DestCol + 1
            If DestCol > DestColCount Then
                MsgBox "Can't find the header " & HeaderText & " in the destination sheet!", vbCritical, "Ahh Nuts!"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        SourceLastRow = wss.Cells(1000000, SourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
        wss.Range(wss.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, SourceCol), wss.Cells(SourceLastRow, SourceCol)).Copy wsd.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, DestCol)
    Next SourceCol
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code neuralgrrove. Its working however, its not working if the header is swapped or any extra header columns has been added (Please refer the attached image for your reference.

Comment: please see my answer above that's working for me. Thanks again for your help :)